# Protein structure visualization

Tags: python, opengl, bioinformatics, vtk, protein-database

I've been asked to work on Protein structure visualization, something like RasMol where a user will be opening a pdb file to get the protein structure.

How I can generate protein structure from the pdb file?

I would like to code in Python and to visualize the structure should I be using OpenGL or VTK? are there any other modules that might help me in this regard?

Comment: Isn't the RasMol source code available?

Comment: Why do you want to implement yet another visualizer? Is it a CG exercise? Or, what kind of feature(s) do you think is/are missing from currently available programs (PyMOL, Chimera, Jmol, ...)? Can you ask in the respective mailing lists for the missing features?

Answer (score 6):

You should try [pymol](http://www.pymol.org/) that has a python interface.

[Here](http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Practical_Pymol_for_Beginners) you have a beginners tutorial of how to script pymol to interact with the views

As a student you can get pymol with no charge from the pymols site. In addition, [Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) provides installers for 32 and 64-bit windows and python 2.6-2.7.

Comment: allow me to be constructve and point out that that is a complete solution that uses python to script the pymol application and nothing else.  also, since he isn't enrolled in college, he would have to pay $20,000 or how much ever it costs to use pymol.

Comment: PyMOL is an open-source program. You can compile your own version from the source code and it does not cost money.
Linux install:
http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Linux_Install
Windows install is a bit tricky, but doable:
http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Windows_Install

Its source code is available as python, or C/C++. You will really benefit from it if you want to start your own implementation.

Comment: @HongboZhu Right, but in the case of windows, it is not difficult at all to start with pymol: as I already indicated, you can get (free) windows binary installers from Gohlke's repository.  Seems marinara did not notice my edit and did not corrected/deleted his comment

Comment: @joaquin, Gohlke's binary compilation is awesome. But notice that there are many restrictions (windows version, python version, CPU variation). I am sure for a lot fresh users it suffices. But there are cases when you bump your head against wall just because the binary does not work.

Answer (score 3):

I think Pymol is not free anymore since it has to be purchased from Schrödinger.
Couple of free programs:
 - JMol (bad!! don't use that except if you have no other choices)
 - PyMol (if you are academic)
 - Yasara 
 - Discovery studio (Accelrys)
 - RasMol (No longer maintained)
 - VMD (the best program for visualizing trajectories). Very powerful but I never used it.

I don't know if you can do scripting in all of them.

I work a lot with PyMol and I did some plug in. The only limit is that you can use it as a viewer but nothing else. For example, you can not get an information by clicking on an atom.

good luck

Comment: You can get the source from sourceforge (http://sourceforge.net/projects/pymol/files/pymol/1.4.1/). If you want binary installers you can get them from Golhke site as I indicated in my post

Comment: There is still the free version of pymol. http://sourceforge.net/projects/pymol/

Pymol is totally capable of doing anything, it just might take some serious exploring/experimenting to figure out to make that happen.

Answer (score 1):

Chimera http://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimera/ is another viewer.  I think its license is more flexible than the pymol one.

You are writing your own?  I think most of these answers are pointing you to implemented viewers.  Good luck though, I imagine it will take a lot of work.